# Any way to make the following chart (pictured) in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

[image: Example chart]

This is the chart that I had in mind. Similar to this chart, I have values for the amount of people that answered Agree/Neutral/Disagree to a specific question. Is there a way to center these answers around the middle of the "Neutral" category, just like in this chart? I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Please post a small sample of your data.

Comment: Without your data I can't give much better advice other than to make sure you have positive and negative data being used and use a Stacked Bar Chart. Chandoo did do a breakdown of this on his site previously - see here: http://chandoo.org/wp/2013/02/21/advances-vs-declines-chart/ - That might help more than an answer here :)

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly easy to accomplish in Excel 2010 (I assume its similar in 2016).  There are a couple different ways to do it, the easiest is to use a stacked bar chart, with:

- negative values for the disagree
- positive values for the agree
- split the neutral in half (divide by two) with one half applied as negative and the other as positive-this will balance along the 0% mid-line.

[image: sample]

There is a detailed, step-by-step tutorial about this called [Diverging Stacked Bar Charts](http://peltiertech.com/diverging-stacked-bar-charts/).